# Tipfy How to use secure cookies to store a cookie in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tipfy

I'm trying to implement stay signed in options using tipfy though I'mm not allowed to use the default Tipfy mechanism.  This is what I have tried so far,

```
    secure_cookie_store = [SecureCookieStore()]
    user_cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
    user_cookie['current_user'] = pickle.dumps(profile_user)
    user_cookie['current_user']['max-age'] = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
    response = Response()
    response.set_cookie('current_user',\
                        secure_cookie_store.get_signed_value('current_user', 'hello'),
                        'test')
```

I'm having a problem of instantiating the `SecureCookieStore()` Object. what argument should I need to pass for its constructor. Please note that i wrote this code segment inside a  handler implemented by the request handler. I will be thankful if anyone provide me a proper answer.